# New layout doesn't exist when referenced in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I added a new layout file to my android project, I tried to reference the layout in my activity class like this SetContentView(Resource.Layout.newlayout), when I built my project, I got newlayout doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this fixed by changing the new layout build action from "BundleResource" to "AndroidResource" in the layout properties tab.

Comment: Glad you could get it solved. If it is all done from that then, go ahead and mark your answer as accepted to finish the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply build the solution once again to get the Layout.

Xamarin android will convert the resource files into int during build.

lemme know if you find any errors.

Answer (score 0):

[Activity(Label = "Hello", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar")]
    public class NewActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.newlayout);
        }
    }

newLayout.axml

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the solution and it should work.

Post errors too if not.